# Should resource lists be community wikis on main site?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[Are there freelanse sites for law advice?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/are-there-freelanse-sites-for-law-advice) is about to be closed.  It certainly merits closure as a list question.  But it might still be a useful community resource.  My understanding is that it *might* be appropriate as a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/241697).  But I'm not sure, and I don't want to act unilaterally to make that conversion.

Does anybody have strong or compelling arguments on this case in particular, or on general guidelines for this Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Open-ended shopping-list type questions are not a good fit for the stack exchange format in general - they are impossible to have a "right answer" to for a start and there is no way of distinguishing good answers from poor answers.

Essentially, this type of question is asking "How do I write an internet search for this?"